# failed to wrap function with lambda

Tags: python, lambda

I want to wrap a function with specified arguments, something like [functools.partial](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functools.html#functools.partial), but it doesn't work as expected:

```
source_codes = (0, 1, 2)

def callback(source, *args):
    print 'callback from source: ', source

funcs = []
for source in source_codes:
    funcs.append(lambda *args: callback(source, *args))

for i, func in enumerate(funcs):
    print 'source expected: ', i
    func()
    print
```

the output:

```
source expected:  0
callback from source:  2

source expected:  1
callback from source:  2

source expected:  2
callback from source:  2
```

But...What I want is:

```
source expected:  0
callback from source:  0

source expected:  1
callback from source:  1

source expected:  2
callback from source:  2
```

I know it works if I use `functools.partial`, but I want to know the real problem in my code... Does the lambda wrapper use a global variable `source` ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The issue in your code is that the lambda expression does not get evaluated untill it gets called.

And then when it gets called, it uses the latest value of `source` . It does not bind value of `source` at the time of creation of the lambda .

Example code to show this behavior  -

```
>>> y = lambda: z
>>> z = 0
>>> y()
0
>>> z  = 1
>>> y()
1
```

Answer (score 2):

`partial` already "freezes" the function's arguments and/or keywords you passed to him so you can simply eliminate `lambda` expression:

```
source_codes = (0, 1, 2)

def callback(source, *args):
    print 'callback from source: ', source

funcs = []
for source in source_codes:
    funcs.append(partial(callback, source))
    source = 30 # don't have any effects over partial function.

for i, func in enumerate(funcs):
    print 'source expected: ', i
    func()
    print
```